# Bug with Foreach, repeating same variable

Tags: php

I built a mail function for a bulk mailer platform im creating, all is working perfectly except for the link i want to replace inside the for each, it is using the same email variable for all remetents, this happent with the variable $tracker aswell but it was fixed adding it inside the sendMail function, same does not work for the str_replace which was supposedly to change the email on each iteration just like it works for sending the mail with each iterate, can't understand why the variable keeps the same if it's iterating.

I have commented the code on where the problem relies it has "// the problem is here " and the for loop is " foreach($emails as $email){"

```
class mailer{

    private $max = 1000; // Máximo de envios de acordo com o servidor
    private $connect;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$password,$db){

        $this->connect = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);  

    }

    public function enviarCampanhas(){

        $connect = $this->connect;
        $data = date("Y-m-d");
        $get = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM campanhas WHERE status = 0 OR status = 3 AND data_inicio LIKE '$data%'");
        $count = $get->num_rows;
        $max_per_campanha = $this->max / $count;

        while($fetch = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            // Falta contagem do array da lista para saber a que emails enviar e depois marcar na campanha quantos já foram enviados

            // Calcular o nr de email na lista
            $cid = $fetch['id'];
            $total = $fetch['total'];
            $enviado = $fetch['enviado'];
            $assunto = utf8_decode($fetch['assunto']);
            $template_id = $fetch['template_id'];
            $get_campaign = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM campanhas WHERE id = '$cid'");
            $fetch_campaign = $get_campaign->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $lista_id = $fetch_campaign['lista_id'];
            $user_id = $fetch_campaign['user_id'];

            $get_template = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id = '$template_id'");
            $fetch_template = $get_template->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $corpo = $fetch_template['codigo'];
            $corpo = str_replace('*','<style>', $corpo);
            $corpo = $corpo."</style>";


            // Trocar links para contabilitizar
            $html = $corpo;
            //Create a new DOM document
            $dom = new DOMDocument;

            //Parse the HTML. The @ is used to suppress any parsing errors
            //that will be thrown if the $html string isn't valid XHTML.
            @$dom->loadHTML($html);

            //Get all links. You could also use any other tag name here,
            //like 'img' or 'table', to extract other tags.
            $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

            //Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
            foreach ($links as $link){
                $old_link = $link->getAttribute('href');
                $new_link = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/scripts/link.php?link=".$link->getAttribute('href')."&campaign_id=".$cid;
                $html = str_replace($old_link,$new_link,$html);
            }

            $corpo = $html;

            $get_lista = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM listas WHERE lista_id = '$lista_id'");
            $fetch_lista = $get_lista->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $emails = $fetch_lista['email'];
            $unsubscribers = $fetch_lista['unsubscribed'];
            $unsubscribers = explode(",",$unsubscribers);
            $emails = explode(",",$emails);
            $emails_new = array_diff_key($emails, array_values($unsubscribers)); 

            $email_nr = 0;
            $count = 1;

            // the problem is here
            foreach($emails as $email){

                if($count == $max_per_campanha){
                    // Parar
                }else{

                    $email = trim($email);
                    $tracker = '<img src="http://website.com/scripts/save_click.php?campaign_id='.$fetch['id'].'&email='.$email.'" />';
                    require_once('../configs/global.php');

                    // This is what is not working properly
                    $novo_url = $config['global']['website']."/scripts/unsubscribed.php?email=$email&campaign_id=$cid";
                    $corpo = str_replace("http://website.com/scripts/unsubscribe.php?replaceparam=x", $novo_url, $corpo);

                    $app = new app;
                    if($app->sendMail($email,$assunto,$tracker."</br>".$corpo) == true){
                        // Guardar emails entregues
                        $connect->query("UPDATE campanhas SET sucess_delivered = sucess_delivered + 1 WHERE id = '$cid'");
                        // Adicionar DB sucess_deliveries , com emails bounced em array
                        //echo $corpo;

                    }else{
                        // Adicionar DB bounced , com emails bounced em array
                        $connect->query("UPDATE campanhas SET bounced = bounced + 1 WHERE id = '$cid'");
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
            }


            // the problem is inside foreach

            $enviado = $enviado + $count;

            if($enviado >= $total){
                $connect->query("UPDATE campanhas SET enviado = '$total',status = 1 WHERE id='$cid'");
                echo "excedeu, completa";
            }else{    
                $connect->query("UPDATE campanhas SET enviado = enviado + '$count' WHERE id='$cid'");
                echo "não completa";
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Since it is iterating each email in the array and that the array is clear readeable, and even the tracker is changing itself it's email i can't understand why the str_replace is sending to each recipient the same unsubscribe email as parameter

Comment: What's in `../configs/global.php`? I'll bet that's the problem, since you use `require_once`, so it's only loaded on the first iteration.

Comment: @Barmar That's just where the website url variable is set , it is defined there, but the thing is that each user receives the correct link of the website via email however is just the $email variable that is not changing on each iteration

Comment: You should place `require_once` outside the loops to reduce needless overhead - function or global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
$corpo = str_replace("http://website.com/scripts/unsubscribe.php?replaceparam=x", $novo_url, $corpo);
```

After the first time, `$corpo` no longer contains `http://website.com/scripts/unsubscribe.php?replaceparam=x`, because it has been replaced with `$novo_url`. So on future iterations it doesn't update `$corpo` at all.

Don't assign the result of the `str_replace()` back to the same variable, assign to a new variable. You need to keep the original string around as a template.

```
foreach($emails as $email){

    if($count == $max_per_campanha){
        // Parar
    }else{

        $email = trim($email);
        $tracker = '<img src="http://website.com/scripts/save_click.php?campaign_id='.$fetch['id'].'&email='.$email.'" />';
        require_once('../configs/global.php');

        // This is what is not working properly
        $novo_url = $config['global']['website']."/scripts/unsubscribed.php?email=$email&campaign_id=$cid";
        $new_corpo = str_replace("http://website.com/scripts/unsubscribe.php?replaceparam=x", $novo_url, $corpo);

        $app = new app;
        if($app->sendMail($email,$assunto,$tracker."</br>".$new_corpo) == true){
            // Guardar emails entregues
            $connect->query("UPDATE campanhas SET sucess_delivered = sucess_delivered + 1 WHERE id = '$cid'");
            // Adicionar DB sucess_deliveries , com emails bounced em array
            //echo $new_corpo;

        }else{
            // Adicionar DB bounced , com emails bounced em array
            $connect->query("UPDATE campanhas SET bounced = bounced + 1 WHERE id = '$cid'");
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow , what a great observation ! Great catch man, ive been hitting my head all day about this issue, i guess i became just tired and was focusing inside the foreach when the problem was outside with the var corpo  great to have other insight, thanks for your help !!